# My UFW is setup yet I can still connect to port 6379 on my server from my home computer

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I am trying to use UFW to secure my server in terms of what types of connections are allowed into the Ubuntu server and outbound.

Below is what I setup, but for some reason I can still connect from my home computer to a service running on the server on port 6379 (redis).

My redis service is running on a docker instance.

**Can someone explain how this can be happening when UFW is active, it is denying all incoming except what I have explicitly allowed?**

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

My IP tables output is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 4950 packets, 278765 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   27788 11520649 ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   27788 11520649 ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5817   327334 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5487   310248 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5487   310248 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    5487   310248 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   46965 43490272 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   46965 43490272 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3349 29211102 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    2731   252253 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   28382  9223021 ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    2842   165226 DOCKER     all  --  *      br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    9661  4638670 ACCEPT     all  --  br-4ee1bbb80fb0 !br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    1540    92400 ACCEPT     all  --  br-4ee1bbb80fb0 br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   17628  2739496 ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   17628  2739496 ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3440   261036 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3440   261036 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3440   261036 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    3440   261036 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-4ee1bbb80fb0 br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.3           tcp dpt:11211
      18      976 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-4ee1bbb80fb0 br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.4           tcp dpt:6379
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-4ee1bbb80fb0 br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.5           tcp dpt:3000
     566    32416 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-4ee1bbb80fb0 br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.6           tcp dpt:443
     593    32440 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-4ee1bbb80fb0 br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.6           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2731   252253 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    9661  4638670 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-4ee1bbb80fb0 !br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   46965 43490272 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      br-4ee1bbb80fb0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   12392  4890923 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   46965 43490272 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       3      234 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
      13      676 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
     314    16176 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2577   139001 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     258    23854 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   20700 11105105 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
      64     8840 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
      64     8840 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
      17      992 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
    6749   381858 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
    6749   381858 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     258    23854 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   13930  2454606 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    3440   261036 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
      64     8840 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6749   381858 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
       0        0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     330    17086 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
      11      660 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
    3429   260376 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     922    53908 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
       7      436 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80
       3      180 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: What type of networking is your docker instance running?

Comment: UFW is just a front end for iptables. It would help if you could post the resulting iptables rule set. Do `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and add it to your question. Also, it is not clear to me that a rule set on your host will block anything to your docket instance.

Comment: @DougSmythies ok I thought it was like that, I have posted IP tables output as request. thanks!

Comment: O.K. There is a global ACCEPT for port 6379 in the DOCKER chain. I'm guessing that is the issue.

Comment: So that must be something Docker creates?  I didn't touch iptables on this new vm instance of ubuntu 18 LTS...